# Linear transformation using bases

Tags: linear-transformations

Let T: $M_2 (\mathbb{R}) \to P_2$ be a linear transformation determined by T $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ = 1 - x² ; 
T $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ = 2 + x + x²;
T $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ = -x + x²;
T $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ = 1 + 2x.

a) Determine T $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 \\
    -2 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

b) Find T $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$, for any a, b, c, d $\in \mathbb{R}$

c) Be  $\mathcal B = \begin{Bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
$
and $\mathcal C$ = {x², 3+x, 2+x+x²} bases from $M_2 (\mathbb{R})$ and from $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ respectively. Determine the matrix T in relation to $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal C$

Please, help me with this exercise, because I'm not doing this right

Comment: What did you try that didn't go right?

Comment: For (a) and (b), you only need to use the linearity of $T$ - can you do that? For (c), recall that the matrix is formed by using inserting the coordinates of the image of the $i$th basis vector from $\mathcal B$ with respect to $\mathcal C$ in the $i$th column. Show us where you get stuck.

Comment: Oh, I mean, the exercise C I'm not doing right. I don't know how to determine this matrix

Comment: The (a) and (b) I could do it. But the (c) I'm really don't know how to do it. I can't "see" how to solve this

Comment: Do you understand my suggestion for (c)? If so, where do you get stuck? If not, what is unclear?

Comment: Well, I'm going to write an answer, showing what I understand. Just a minute

Comment: That's fine. Rather than writing it in an answer, you can update/edit your question to include your own work/attempt.

Answer (score 0):

In view of b), by linearity,
$$T \left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b\\ c & d\end{array}\right) = 
a T\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)
+ b T\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)
+ c T\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)
+ d T\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)=
a(1-x^2) + b(2+x+x^2) + c(-x+x^2) +d (1+2x).
$$
Expansion gives a real-valued polynomial of degree at most 2.

Comment: Yeah, I did it in the same way you did it. But the real problem is in (c).
I tried to use the (b) in (c), but it wasn't clear what I had to do

Answer (score 0):

In base $\mathcal B$ we have the first value $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1  \\
    0 & 0  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$. Writting this value, using the linear transformation from the exercice, I got: T$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1  \\
    0 & 0  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ = [(1-x²)+(2+x+x²)] = (3+x).
Is that right?

If, this is right, I need to describe this in the bases $\mathcal C$. Lookin at the base, I got     \begin{bmatrix}
    0   \\
    1   \\
    0
    \end{bmatrix}.
Is that right?
Or I'm missing something?

Comment: This is correct but only part of the work, you found the coordinates with respect to $\mathcal C$ of the **first** vector in basis $\mathcal B$ so this will be the **first** column of the matrix $T$; proceed with the other three vectors from $\mathcal B$ to get the next three columns.

Comment: I did the rest on a paper here.
The first and the second vector, are equal to the bases C. I mean, I find (3+x) and (2+x+x²).

But the others, I found (2x²-x+1) and (3+x-x²). How can I describe then in the bases C?

Comment: If it's not clear "by inspection", you solve a system: make a linear combination of the base vectors of C and find the required coefficients.

Comment: Ohh, I see. The (3+x-x²) can be write as {-1,1,0}, right?

Comment: Correct! I didn't check if 3+x-x² is right, but your method to get the coefficients seems to be alright now.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in a comment to another answer that you “tried to use (b) in (c).” That’s certainly a valid way to approach the problem instead of essentially starting over from scratch for (c). You’ve found a (hopefully $3\times4$) matrix $M=[T]_{\mathcal E}^{\mathcal E'}$ that expresses $T$ relative to the standard ordered bases $\mathcal E'$ and $\mathcal E$ of $M_2(\mathbb R)$ and $P_2$, respectively. In order to compute $[T]_{\mathcal C}^{\mathcal B}$ you just need to multiply by the appropriate change-of-basis matrices: $$[T]_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal C} = [\operatorname{id}]_{\mathcal C}^{\mathcal E}[T]_{\mathcal E}^{\mathcal E'}[\operatorname{id}]_{\mathcal E'}^{\mathcal B}.$$ (Here the superscripts denote the “input” bases and subscripts the “output” bases.) Now, the columns of the change-of-basis matrix that converts from $\mathcal B$ to the standard basis are, as always, the images of the elements of $\mathcal B$ expressed relative to the standard basis—i.e., the coordinate vectors of the elements of $\mathcal B$. Calling this matrix $B$, and similarly for the matrix $C$, that means that you have to compute $C^{-1}MB$.

Whether this is more or less work than computing it directly from the definition of $T$ and the two bases depends on what you’re comfortable with. Inverting a $3\times 3$ matrix ($C$) is tedious, but not very difficult, and in fact that part of the product can be computed via row-reduction of the augmented matrix $[C\mid MB]$: when you’re done, you end up with $[I_3\mid C^{-1}MB]$.